# Dockerizing an app

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a java application. I know how to start a Docker container and retrieve images from here and there, but how do I pass my java application files to Docker, e.g. from a version control or other directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can COPY your files to the new docker image of your app. First, create your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) and then [build](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/) the image, and then run it.
2. Another way is to run "ready to use" official images and mount your files via [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

**Step by step Dockerfile example:**

**a)** Look at this repo https://github.com/starikovs/stupidbox, here is the plugin's code and Dockerfile.

**b)** Dockerfile has the following commands:

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Which means that you say to docker to COPY all the files from the current dir to a new docker image. VOLUME is a special dir where your data/files are stored, also you can mount any folder as a volume.

**c)** To build a new docker image out of a Dockerfile just `cd` to that dir and run `docker build . -t imagename`, after build you can check that your image has been built with help of `docker images`.

**d)** Your image is ready to use and you can run it now. Of course, Dockerfile has a lot of other options, this example is jut to show the flow.

**"ready to use" official images example:**

On the other hand, you can use ready to use official images. Take a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ NGINX official image. With help of one command `docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx` you can run nginx and mount your files `-v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro` to the image.

Comment: Sorry, but how would this actually be done step-by-step in option 1. ? Would the dockerfile specify how the copying is done? 2. You mean that I would mount the "deploy" folder of the application server, and that way pass in the e.g. .ear file?

Comment: @user1340582 I've updated the answer, home that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the volumes option with `docker run` and mount a directory(or directories) containing your java application and a small bash script that will start it up.  The ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile can point to that bash script by name.